# Angular2 beta 7 infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I get an infinite loop using beta7, this is the Firefox's stacktrace:

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
DebugDomRenderer</DebugDomRenderer.prototype.createText@http:   //localhost:2067/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:7184:11
viewFactory_t0@viewFactory_t:256:18
viewFactory_t0@viewFactory_t:266:1
viewFactory_t0@viewFactory_t:266:1
viewFactory_t0@viewFactory_t:266:1
viewFactory_t0@viewFactory_t:266:1
viewFactory_t0@viewFactory_t:266:1
...
```

Before the jump to beta7 everything works well, but if I switch now to beta6, I get the same error. So I think the problem was present even before. 
As you can see in the AppComponent class I'm handling 2 routes: Main e NotFound. The strange thing is that if I write an not existing url in the browser (e.g. localhost:2056/asdad) the NotFound page is displayed correctly.

My packages:

```
   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.20",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15",
```

My tsd:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
      "commit": "9027703c0bd831319dcdf7f3169f7a468537f448"
    },
    "bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts": {
      "commit": "9027703c0bd831319dcdf7f3169f7a468537f448"
    }
  },
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
  }
}
```

My boot:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

My routing class:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, Location, Instruction, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {MainComponent} from './components/sections/main.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './components/sections/not-found.component';
import {EventEmitterService} from './services/event-emitter.service';
import {NavigationService, Routes} from './services/navigation.service'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [EventEmitterService, NavigationService]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/' , name: Routes.Main , component: MainComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path:'/not-found' , name: Routes.NotFound , component: NotFoundComponent}
])
export class AppComponent
{   
    public constructor(private _router: Router, _location:Location) 
    {
        _router.recognize(_location.path()).then((instruction: Instruction) => {
            if (!instruction)
                _router.recognize('/not-found').then((instruction: Instruction) => _router.navigateByInstruction(instruction, true));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: turning back to beta0 everything works fine.
I would like to understand what is going wrong. I don't think I'm the only one with this problem. My code follows strictly the code of the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

After a terrible day I found out the problem.

Using Angular2.**beta6** when you compile the .ts files you get the error below.

To avoid such error it is suggested to use this line of code in the boot (main) class:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

This line of code removes the compile error **but** causes an infinite loop when you open the app (to be precise, the error is present only if a component contains two or more children components)

This is the above mentioned compiling error (the strange thing is that even if you get this error, the website works great):

```
node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(3,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(4,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(14,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(24,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(25,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.d.ts(436,103): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.d.ts(436,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(13,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(14,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(95,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(96,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(97,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(14,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(78,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(1,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(3,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/angular2/src/http/headers.d.ts(43,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/http/url_search_params.d.ts(11,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(75,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(85,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(22,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(72,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(77,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(77,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(65,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(65,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(72,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(77,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(100,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(154,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(159,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(159,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```